# Open Browser Action's Popup with keyboard shortcut

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a Google Chrome extension with a Browser Action Popup. When the user clicks on the icon, the popup appears.

Is there a way to open this popup with a keyboard shortcut like <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+something?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add a `"commands"` object to your `manifest.json`, as shown at https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands. If your extension's popup is a `"browser_action"` popup (indicated by a `"browser_action"` key in your `manifest.json`), you'll need the `"_execute_browser_action"` command; for a `"page_action"` popup, you'll need the `"_execute_page_action"` command. An example `manifest.json` using the former looks like this:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Example Extension",
  "description": "La la la",
  "version": "1.0",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "commands": {
    "_execute_browser_action": {
      "suggested_key": {
        "default": "Ctrl+Shift+E",
        "linux": "Ctrl+Shift+K",
        "windows": "Alt+Shift+P",
        "mac": "Alt+Shift+P"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that, per the docs:

> Certain Chrome shortcuts (e.g. window management) always take priority over Extension Command shortcuts and can not be overwritten.

As far as I know, there's no canonical list of what these commands are; you just have to experiment with different possible suggested shortcuts until you find one that actually works.

Answer (score 6):

The [chrome.commands api](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands.html) enables the user to bind hotkeys (with your suggestion for the hotkey) that will trigger commands such as opening the browser action.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, currently not possible. Here is corresponding [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=50356), you can star it.

Comment: As noted in the other answers here, this is no longer correct.