# How can I specify a hotkey for my browser action?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser-action

Is it possible to specify a hotkey that will activate a [Google Chrome browser action](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/browserAction.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can manipulate almost every other aspect of the browserAction and the popup (including closing it) but it cannot be triggered programatically.

@hamczu is right that the only way to bind global keyboard shortcuts is to inject a [Content Script](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html) that listens for keystrokes in every page.

However you will not be able to make those keystrokes (or anything else) trigger the browserAction.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look to [Vimium](https://github.com/philc/vimium/) project source. Global hotkeys are done by binding keyboard events in content script and communicate to background page. As authors say in [Wiki](https://github.com/philc/vimium/wiki/Chromium-bugs-we%27re-tracking) there is no way "to add global keyboard shortcuts (without using a content script)".

Unfortunately I have found [related issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=50356) in the bugtracker and it seems there is no way to so so.

Answer (score 0):

The [chrome.commands api](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands.html) enables the user to bind hotkeys (with your suggestion for the hotkey) that will trigger commands such as opening the browser action.

Duplicate of [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15980126/777203).